# SQL Server Fixed number of rows per recordID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, **Product** and **Pricing**. Table **Product** is the parent table whereas **Pricing** is the child table. When I query table B using foreign keys from Product, I would like to generate exactly 11 rows for each foreign key, with or without data(null-fill all empty rows and columns)

Below is sample of what I have so far. Does not work right but essentially my goal is to, for each ProductID, generate 11 rows, fill the empty row columns with null values

```
SELECT TOP 11
   row_number() over(order by TheCount desc) AS row_num,  PRODID,  packageID
FROM
    (
    select count(*) AS TheCount , PRODID ,max(PricingID) AS packageID
    from 
       Product left  outer  join   Pricing on PRODID = ProductID 
    group by PRODID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 11 -1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NUK
    FROM sys.columns
    ) T
```

Eg

```
 row_num        PRODID                                    PRICINGID                               COSBeginQty          COSColCode   COSTrade  COSTypeOfPrice  COSIsActive 
   1              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877      F82F533E-C1A0-4DC5-BB2C-06FFF2E59C18        2                 NULL              T2        A              1
   2              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877      372E6B36-F9D1-4EFA-8A15-08CE673EFFBA        12                NULL              T1        A              1
   3              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877      45E77A6F-DC2A-44BF-B6AE-0BE27BD2205F        7                 NULL              T2        A              1
   4              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
   5              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
   6              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
   7              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
   8              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
   9              A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
   10             A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
   11             A10D8642-F6DA-499E-9FC9-024FED104877              NULL                                NULL              NULL              NULL      NULL       NULL
```

Here is a [*SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7ca0/2) Link that shows data and a working query that I am working to extend so that it extends to the 11th, i.e. displays 11 rows as columns.

Using Damiens sample code, I have been able to put together the code below. It works to crossapply the elements from the product table to the Pricing table, however, I prefer a case where it does not apply the same PricingID to all of the ProductIDs from the product Table but to only that particular ProductId that the pricing record applies to.

Comment: Why do you need the empty rows?

Comment: I need them for further processing that I need to do later on.

Comment: Apart from cross Apply, what other kind of join can I use to obtain the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

The basic way would use a number table, `ROW_NUMBER()` and a left join:

```
select
    *
from
    sys.tables st
        cross join
    (select distinct number from master..spt_values where number between 1 and 11) n
        left join
    (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY object_id order by name) rn from sys.columns) sc
        on
            st.object_id = sc.object_id and
            sc.rn = n.number
```

(Here, the `spt_values` query is taking the place of a numbers table)

You should be able to run this in any database and see how the scheme generally works. The `CROSS JOIN` creates 11 rows for each parent row. Then we join to the first 11 children, selected using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

I don't have your data, so I didn't attempt to write it using your existing queries.

Comment: I Updated my post with a link to SQLFiddle that shows data and an existing procedure I would like to extend so that instead of producing just the 3rd set, goes all the way to 11.

Comment: I was wondering if you could further help me. I have my code with data at sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f227/2 . What I would like is to generate 11 rows for only the parent data that has a record in the child table

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive query. Something like this:

```
;WITH tmp(i, tablename,total) AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name), CONVERT(varchar(MAX),name), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=t.object_id)
FROM sys.tables t
UNION ALL
SELECT i+1, tablename+' COPY '+CONVERT(varchar(4),i), total FROM tmp WHERE i <=20
)SELECT * FROM tmp ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Comment: Hi again,
I just had a case where the size is variable.
Quick & easy example:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/cac01a92-265d-460a-9380-995ed2df7ae9/

Answer (score 0):

+1 on using a numbers table... i don't have a numbers table so i'll use the values constructor to create one for example (values construct works in sql server 2008+).

```
select TP.ProductID, TNum.num, Tprices.PriceID
from Product TP
INNER JOIN (select num from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) as T1(num)) TNum ON TNum.num BETWEEN 1 and 11
LEFT JOIN (select TP2.PriceID, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY TP2.ProductID ORDER BY TP2.PriceID DESC) RowNum from Prices TP2) Tprices ON TNum.num = Tprices.RowNum
```